# View not updated if service.variable got changed

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-observable

I am learning Angular2 after I learned AngularJS.

Actually I got a problem to solve View updates. 
Think this could get done with Oberving, but any try to implement an observable variable failed.

My Problem: 
My Training APP got three rows (header, extension, status), each row got a component. In Header I got a select which gets feed by a service.

The service got to static values, the collection for the select and the selected value. So far so good. But I would like to display the selected value on the content component, without binding it between the components.

Heres my code:
HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <app-header fxLayout="row"> 
        <app-user fxLayout="column"></app-user>
    </app-header>
    <app-extension fxLayout="row" fxFlex></app-extension>
    <app-status fxLayout="row"></app-status>
</div>
```

User Service:

```
export class UserService {

    private static currentUser: User;
    private users: User[];

}

public constructor() {
    this.users = [];
    this.users.push(new User(1, 'Erster User!'));
    this.users.push(new User(2, 'Zweiter User!'));
    this.select(1);
}

public getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public getUser(userId: number = 0) {
        for (const user of this.users) {
            if (user.getId() === userId) {
                return user;
            }
        }
    }

    public getStamp() {
        return UserService.stamp;
    }

    public select(userId: number) {
        UserService.currentUser = this.getUser(userId);
    }

    public getCurrent() {
        return UserService.currentUser;
    }

    users: User[];

    // *** how to inject the service as a singleton instance?
    constructor(@Inject(UserService) private _userService: UserService) {
        this.users = this._userService.getUsers();
    }
```

UserComponent

```
users: User[];

    // *** how to inject the service as a singleton instance?
    constructor(@Inject(UserService) private _userService: UserService) {
        this.users = this._userService.getUsers();
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this._userService.select(event.source.value);
    }
```

ExtensionComponent

```
currentUser: User;

    constructor(@Inject(UserService) private _userService: UserService) {
        this.currentUser = this._userService.getCurrent();
    }
```

In Extension Component I can display the selected user, with any event (click, keypress, etc) but I would like to get it updated, each time when userService changes it.

I tried many examples from internet but none worked.

Can anyone assist me to understand the solution? What would be the best practice? What are the simplest code examples to understand it?

Regards n00n

Comment: Either the view must get the current user from the service **every time** (and not just once when the component is created), or the service must emit an event so that the component know when to refresh it state.

Comment: what errors did occur when trying to implement observables?

Comment: Get no error, tried with observable, was not working. How to emit in angular2?